# Understanding a recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I want to understand the following recurrence relation from https://oeis.org/A140993.
I see the triangle it creates, but I don't understand how to generate the triangle from the formula.

Can someone explain it and give an example of calculating a few levels of it?

Triangle read by rows:
recurrence G(n,k): G(n, n)=G(n+1, 1)=1,
G(n+2, 2)=2,
G(n+3, k)=G(n+1, k-1)+G(n+1, k-2)+G(n+2, k-1) for k:=2..(n+2), 0<=k<=n.

Triangle begins:
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 2 4 1
1 2 5 7 1
1 2 5 11 12 1
1 2 5 12 23 20 1
1 2 5 12 28 46 33 1
1 2 5 12 29 63 89 54 1
1 2 5 12 29 69 137 168 88 1
1 2 5 12 29 70 161 289 311 143 1
1 2 5 12 29 70 168 367 594 567 232 1
1 2 5 12 29 70 169 399 817 1194 1021 376 1
1 2 5 12 29 70 169 407 934 1778 2355 1820 609 1

Comment: Can you give an example of your attempted calculations and show us where your answer isn't matching the output given?

Comment: I would love to, but I cannot understand the recurrence relation syntax at all. I am new to them and have never worked with them before. I read http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jiang/cs141/recur-tut.txt to better understand, but it did not help me understand this one particularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $G(n,k)$ appears in row $n$, column $k$ of the array. We’re told that $G(n,n)=1$ for all $n\ge 1$, so the diagonal is all ones. This includes $G(1,1)$, the element at the top of the array. We’re also told that $G(n+1,1)=1$ for all $n\ge 1$; that says that $G(n,1)=1$ for $n\ge 2$, and we already knew that $G(1,1)=1$, so the entire first column is all ones. So far we have this:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&1&-&1\\
4&1&-&-&1\\
5&1&-&-&-&1
\end{array}$$

Next we learn that $G(n+2,2)=2$ for all $n\ge 1$; that is, $G(n,2)=2$ for all $n\ge 3$. Now we have:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&1&2&1\\
4&1&2&-&1\\
5&1&2&-&-&1
\end{array}\tag{1}$$

Finally we come to the main recurrence:

$$G(n+3,k)=G(n+1,k-1)+G(n+1,k-2)+G(n+2,k-1)\tag{2}$$

for $k=2,3,\ldots,n+1$. The use of $n+3$ really just says that we’re talking about row $4$ and later; we could instead write $(2)$ as

$$G(n,k)=G(n-2,k-1)+G(n-2,k-2)+G(n-1,k-1)\tag{3}$$

for $n\ge 4$ and $2\le k\le n-1$. This says that each entry whose value has not been determined by the earlier clauses of the definition of $G$ is the sum of three entries above and to the left of it, as you can see from the following small piece of the array:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} \hline
G(n-2,k-2)&G(n-2,k-1)\\ \hline
&G(n-1,k-1)\\ \hline
&&G(n,k)\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The first missing entry in $(1)$ is $G(4,3)$; according to $(3)$, this is

$$G(4,3)=G(2,2)+G(2,1)+G(3,2)=1+1+2=4\;,$$

as also shown by the brown and red entries below:

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&\color{brown}1&\color{brown}1\\
3&1&\color{brown}2&1\\
4&1&2&\color{red}4&1\\
5&1&2&-&-&1
\end{array}$$

Similarly,

$$G(5,3)=G(3,2)+G(3,1)+G(4,2)=2+1+2=5\;:$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&\color{brown}1&\color{brown}2&1\\
4&1&\color{brown}2&4&1\\
5&1&2&\color{red}5&-&1
\end{array}$$

Finally,

$$G(5,4)=G(3,3)+G(3,2)+G(4,3)=1+2+4=7\;:$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
n\backslash k&1&2&3&4&5\\ \hline
1&1\\
2&1&1\\
3&1&\color{brown}2&\color{brown}1\\
4&1&2&\color{brown}4&1\\
5&1&2&5&\color{red}7&1
\end{array}$$

And the array continues to grow in this fashion.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent explanation! Now I will reread it until I get it.

Comment: @JLee: You’re welcome; feel free to leave a question if anything isn’t clear.

Comment: I get it now. And it's actually not a difficult thing conceptually, but the syntax looked like Greek to me, and I was stuck. If you don't mind, would you verify the conclusion that I drew from this recurrence relation here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1033971/number-of-ways-you-can-partition-a-string-into-substrings-of-certain-length/1034230#1034230    My intuition says I am correct, but I haven't formally proven it (and don't know how to).